# Implenting Mailgun's Jquery Email Validator on current form

Tags: jquery, mailgun

I'm trying to integrate Mailgun's jQuery email validator into a current form.  So far I've been able to get the email validation messages to appear on my site.  However, I'm not able to get it to work with the submit button properly.  It either gives a validation message, and let's nobody through on submit, or it shows the message and lets everybody through.

You can see the code I've copied over: https://github.com/mailgun/validator-demo/blob/master/index.html

I hooked that into my own form, and when I press Enter or click the Submit button, nothing happens.  I'm assuming it has something to do with the Return nothing code within the functions at the bottom.  But I can't figure out what to put there to get it to show the validation message, and then allow a submit it it's successful, and not allow someone to pass if it's not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in possession of an API Key (in this case you can use the public key you can retrieve from the control panel in mailgun) you can try the live demo here: http://mailgun.github.io/validator-demo/

The code is the same, maybe if you can edit your question and add the code you're using I can help you debug it.

:)

Comment: hey, do you know why my own public key doesn't work? if use public key from demo page the validator works well

Answer (score 0):

The MailGun jQuery example is an async request and the submit process works without waiting for response from the mailgun api.

You need to make a synchronous request to a webmethod. You may use the following code

```
function validateEmailByMailGun(Email){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "alpha.aspx/CheckEmail",
        data: "{UserName:'" + Email + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function Success(msg) {
            isMailGunValidEmail = msg.d; //can have true, false or error
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            isMailGunValidEmail = false;
            isMailGunError = true;
        }
    });
}
```

In your alpha.aspx, create a webmethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static object CheckEmail(string UserName)
    {
        var http = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/address/validate?address=" + UserName);
        http.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("api","put your public key here");
        http.Timeout = 5000;
        try
        {
            var response = http.GetResponse();
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            var content = sr.ReadToEnd();
            JSON.JsonObject js = new JSON.JsonObject(content);
            return Convert.ToBoolean(js["is_valid"]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```